# How can I use items of a list as input for a function in a loop in R?

Tags: r, function, loops

I am new to R as well as stackoverflow, so please forgive me my naivite and possible mistakes. My goal is to create a dataframe of transaction details for ethereum transactions. The function I use for a single transaction is:

```
library(devtools)
library(etherscanr)

devtools::install_github("dirkschumacher/etherscanr")
etherscan_transactions("0x3cd751e6b0078be393132286c442345e5dc49699")
```

The number in the brackets of the function is the wallet address for which I need the details. So far so good. This works just fine. However, I need to do this for thousands of addresses, which is why I want to loop this function over a list. This is where I am stuck and ask for your help. I tried different approaches including lapply and for loops, looking something like that:

```
transto <- transaction_sample$to

for(i in 1:length(transto)) {
  transtodetail <- etherscan_transactions(i)
}
```

This is the error I get:
Error in etherscan_transactions(i) : is.character(account) is not TRUE

This is what the list of wallet adrresses looks like:

```
 head(transto)
[1] "0x3cd751e6b0078be393132286c442345e5dc49699"
[2] "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7"
[3] "0x2260fac5e5542a773aa44fbcfedf7c193bc2c599"
[4] "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7"
[5] "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7"
[6] "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7"
```

I am grateful for any type of hints.

Comment: Try `results  <- lapply(transto, etherscan_transactions)`. This will put the results of your function call into a list. The reason your attempt didn’t work is that you were passing your index to the function, not the value of the vector at the index.

Comment: Thanks, I think that solved the problem, however I get the error: "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" even though I used as.list, any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Search StackOverflow for that error message. It has been asked and answered countless times. If you still can’t see the problem in your case, edit your post to provide a *minimal reproducible example*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
  #' The data:
transto <- c("0x3cd751e6b0078be393132286c442345e5dc49699",
             "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7",
             "0x2260fac5e5542a773aa44fbcfedf7c193bc2c599",
             "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7",
             "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7",
             "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7")
```

Using a modified/fake version of `etherscan_transactions` tells you what has been happening:

```r
fake_etherscan_transactions <- function(i_arg) print(i_arg)

for(i in 1:length(transto)) {
  transtodetail <- fake_etherscan_transactions(i)
}
#> [1] 1
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 3
#> [1] 4
#> [1] 5
#> [1] 6
```

You passed the index to `etherscan_transactions()` instead of the value at each index.

Here are some solutions. Just replace `fake_etherscan_transactions` with `etherscan_transactions`.
Solution 1: use the index

```r
for(i in 1:length(transto)) {
  transtodetail <- fake_etherscan_transactions(transto[i])
}
#> [1] "0x3cd751e6b0078be393132286c442345e5dc49699"
#> [1] "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7"
#> [1] "0x2260fac5e5542a773aa44fbcfedf7c193bc2c599"
#> [1] "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7"
#> [1] "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7"
#> [1] "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7"
```

Solution 2: use `transto` as vector in the `for` loop

```r
for(i in transto) {
  transtodetail <- fake_etherscan_transactions(i)
}
#> [1] "0x3cd751e6b0078be393132286c442345e5dc49699"
#> [1] "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7"
#> [1] "0x2260fac5e5542a773aa44fbcfedf7c193bc2c599"
#> [1] "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7"
#> [1] "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7"
#> [1] "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7"
```

Solution 3: use `sapply` over `transto` (as proposed by @Limey).

```r
sapply(transto, fake_etherscan_transactions)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much, I think the sapply solution is the most efficient one , however I still get the error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. Should I mark this question then as solved nonetheless since it has not much to do with the original question?

Comment: It makes sense, yes. You posed the question including the snippet of the data you provided. And that is solved. Now you have a new problem. That'd be a new question. Unfortunately, yes.